# Calculate quartiles of data set

Tags: calculations, expl3

**Comment:** The following code is taken from egreg's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233222/15874).

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n

\prop_new:N \g_svend_elev_prop
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {A} {6}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {B} {0}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {C} {0}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {D} {3}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {E} {0}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {F} {2}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {G} {1}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {H} {1}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {I} {1}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {J} {5}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {K} {0}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {L} {3}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {M} {7}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {N} {3}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {O} {1}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {P} {1}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {Q} {0}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {R} {0}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {S} {0}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {T} {2}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {U} {1}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {V} {2}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {W} {0}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {X} {2}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {Y} {1}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {Z} {1}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {Aa} {4}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {Ab} {6}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {Ac} {1}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {Ad} {1}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {Ae} {6}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {Af} {2}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {Ag} {0}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {Ah} {3}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {Ai} {2}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {Aj} {1}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {Ak} {0}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {Al} {0}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {Am} {0}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {An} {0}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {Ao} {0}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_elev_prop {Ap} {4}

\prop_new:N \g_svend_count_prop
\prop_new:N \g_svend_count_zero_prop
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_count_zero_prop { 0 } { 0 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_count_zero_prop { 1 } { 0 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_count_zero_prop { 2 } { 0 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_count_zero_prop { 3 } { 0 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_count_zero_prop { 4 } { 0 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_count_zero_prop { 5 } { 0 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_count_zero_prop { 6 } { 0 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_svend_count_zero_prop { 7 } { 0 }
\prop_gset_eq:NN \g_svend_count_prop \g_svend_count_zero_prop

\tl_new:N \l_svend_number_tl
\tl_new:N \l_svend_count_tl

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\elev}{m}
 {
  \svend_get_item:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\countappearances}{}
 {
  % now \elev will also count
  \cs_set_eq:NN \elev \svend_get_item_count:n
  % reinitialize the counter property list
  \prop_set_eq:NN \g_svend_count_prop \g_svend_count_zero_prop
 }

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\HowMany}{m}
 {
  \prop_item:Nn \g_svend_count_prop { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \svend_get_item:n #1
 {
  \prop_item:Nn \g_svend_elev_prop { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \svend_get_item_count:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_svend_number_tl { \svend_get_item:n { #1 } }
  % print the entry
  \tl_use:N \l_svend_number_tl
  % get the current count
  \tl_set:Nx \l_svend_count_tl
   {
    \prop_item:NV \g_svend_count_prop \l_svend_number_tl
   }
  % advance the count by 1
  \tl_set:Nx \l_svend_count_tl { \int_to_arabic:n { \l_svend_count_tl + 1 } }
  % update the property
  \prop_gput:NVV \g_svend_count_prop \l_svend_number_tl \l_svend_count_tl
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { NV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_gput:Nnn { NVV }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\newcommand*\HowManyCumuA{\HowMany{0}}
\newcommand*\HowManyCumuB{\calc{\HowManyCumuA+\HowMany{1}}}
\newcommand*\HowManyCumuC{\calc{\HowManyCumuB+\HowMany{2}}}
\newcommand*\HowManyCumuD{\calc{\HowManyCumuC+\HowMany{3}}}
\newcommand*\HowManyCumuE{\calc{\HowManyCumuD+\HowMany{4}}}
\newcommand*\HowManyCumuF{\calc{\HowManyCumuE+\HowMany{5}}}
\newcommand*\HowManyCumuG{\calc{\HowManyCumuF+\HowMany{6}}}
\newcommand*\HowManyCumuH{\calc{\HowManyCumuG+\HowMany{7}}}
\newcommand*\HowManyTotale{\HowManyCumuH}
\newcommand*\frequency[1]{\calc{round(#1/\HowManyTotale*100,1)}}
\newcommand*\frequencyCumuA{\frequency{\HowMany{0}}}
\newcommand*\frequencyCumuB{\calc{\frequencyCumuA+\frequency{\HowMany{1}}}}
\newcommand*\frequencyCumuC{\calc{\frequencyCumuB+\frequency{\HowMany{2}}}}
\newcommand*\frequencyCumuD{\calc{\frequencyCumuC+\frequency{\HowMany{3}}}}
\newcommand*\frequencyCumuE{\calc{\frequencyCumuD+\frequency{\HowMany{4}}}}
\newcommand*\frequencyCumuF{\calc{\frequencyCumuE+\frequency{\HowMany{5}}}}
\newcommand*\frequencyCumuG{\calc{\frequencyCumuF+\frequency{\HowMany{6}}}}
\newcommand*\frequencyCumuH{\calc{\frequencyCumuG+\frequency{\HowMany{7}}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{table}
\centering
\countappearances
\begin{tabular}{*{14}{c}}
\toprule
\elev{A}  & \elev{B}  & \elev{C}  & \elev{D}  & \elev{E}  & \elev{F}  & \elev{G}  &
\elev{H}  & \elev{I}  & \elev{J}  & \elev{K}  & \elev{L}  & \elev{M}  & \elev{N}    \\[0.5ex]
\elev{O}  & \elev{P}  & \elev{Q}  & \elev{R}  & \elev{S}  & \elev{T}  & \elev{U}  &
\elev{V}  & \elev{W}  & \elev{X}  & \elev{Y}  & \elev{Z}  & \elev{Aa} & \elev{Ab}   \\[0.5ex]
\elev{Ac} & \elev{Ad} & \elev{Ae} & \elev{Af} & \elev{Ag} & \elev{Ah} & \elev{Ai} &
\elev{Aj} & \elev{Ak} & \elev{Al} & \elev{Am} & \elev{An} & \elev{Ao} & \elev{Ap}   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{*{7}{S[table-format = 2.1]} S[table-format = 3]}
\toprule
{$F(0)$} & {$F(1)$} & {$F(2)$} & {$F(3)$} &
{$F(4)$} & {$F(5)$} & {$F(6)$} & {$F(7)$}   \\
\calc{round(\frequencyCumuA,1)} & \calc{round(\frequencyCumuB,1)} &
\calc{round(\frequencyCumuC,1)} & \calc{round(\frequencyCumuD,1)} &
\calc{round(\frequencyCumuE,1)} & \calc{round(\frequencyCumuF,1)} &
\calc{round(\frequencyCumuG,1)} & \calc{round(\frequencyCumuH,1)}   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

**Question:** How can I get LaTeX to calculate the quartiles of the dataset? I would like to have something like the macros

> `\quartileA`, `\quartileB`, `\quartileC`

with the corresponding output

> `0`, `1`, `3`

(in this particular case).

**Note:** For a ranked set of data values, the *quartiles* *A*, *B*, and *C* are the values of the data where the cumulated frequnecies reach 25 %, 50 %, and 75 %, respectively.

In the example above, 25 % is reached for F(0) (since F(0) is the first value after 25 % is reached; therefore I want the output `0` in this particlar case), 50 % is reached for F(1) (since F(1) is the first value after 50 % is reached; therefore I want the output `1` in this particlar case), and 75 % is reached for F(3) (since F(3) is the first value after 75 % is reached; therefore I want the output `3` in this particlar case).

P.S. At least that's the definition that's used at the level I'm teaching at.

Comment: Maybe a fast definition of quartiles for non statisticians?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Personally, I would use R with the knitr package to manage the statistics in the tex file.  This would allow you to use a tool designed for statistics and use LaTeX for the formatting of the final output.  Another advantage is that if you intent to use any graphics the R-knitr system will be much easier. Go to http://yihui.name/knitr/ for details and examples.

Comment: @R.Schumacher Good points but I would really like to keep it in the LaTeX world. (Ultimately I need to teach the kids what a box plot is and how to draw such a thing -- keeping it all in a LaTeX file is preferable for me.)

Comment: @egreg Has my updated to the question been of any help? `:)`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Sorry, being a mathematician, I can understand nothing about statistics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*update* This update has code which discovers on the fly the possible values. These values must be numeric but need not be integers. The incompatibility mentioned earlier with Beamer was only due to the fact that with Beamer it appears impossible (if not using tricks perhaps which I did not try to discover) to use tokens such as `#1` or `#2` in a frame; in particular it is impossible to define a command in a frame.

Any way the update does it with Beamer nevertheless. See bottom half of answer.

---

**First answer**

In this answer I implement a `\Percentile` macro. The possible values of the data (from `0` to `7`) is however hard-coded in the macro.

I use `\numexpr` when convenient, else I use `xintfrac` (mainly because I didn't want to rewrite a rounding to fixed point routine, but at the level here everything could be done with `\numexpr`). For convenience of coding I use `\xintFor` of package `xinttools`.

I briefly mentioned that this made me discover:

1. I can not use a naked `\xintFor` in a Beamer frame, somehow the Beamer parsing does not like seeing the `#` character,

1a. This has nothing to do whatsoever with `\xintFor`: with Beamer it is impossible to define a command (which will use `#1`, or `#2`, etc...) inside a frame !!! As `\xintFor` per its nature works with `#1` etc.. tokens, its use is impossible in a beamer frame. Naturally a macro can use it internally.

2. I can not use either `\xintFor` in a tabular with an `S` column from `siunitx`.

I dropped Beamer and for the tabular with `siunitx` I used expandable macros as a replacement (but even then I discovered I could not use them in the generality I expected, when `siunitx` is used).

As for the code, it uses internal macros to store individual data, for efficiency of data retrieval.

```
%\documentclass{beamer} 
% Beamer is **incompatible** with non hidden \xintFor in  a frame !!!
% NO (unhidden) \xintFor in a Beamer frame !!

% Also for some reason latex+dvipng raises an error here

% This is dvipng (dvipng (TeX Live)) 1.14 Copyright 2002-2010 Jan-Ake Larsson
% [1 <raw PostScriptdvipng warning: No image output from inclusion of raw PostScript >] 

% must go via pdflatex
\documentclass[varwidth, border=6pt, ignorerest=false]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
% siunitx is incompatible with use of \xintFor in a tabular !!
%

% \usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{xintfrac, xinttools}
% xintfrac mainly for \xintRound because everything else can be emulated with
% \numexpr or \dimexpr in this context
% xinttools for the convenience of \xintFor

\newcommand*\SvendData
                {{{A}{6}}%
                 {{B}{0}}%
                 {{C}{0}}%
                 {{D}{3}}%
                 {{E}{0}}%
                 {{F}{2}}%
                 {{G}{1}}%
                 {{H}{1}}%
                 {{I}{1}}%
                 {{J}{5}}%
                 {{K}{0}}%
                 {{L}{3}}%
                 {{M}{7}}%
                 {{N}{3}}%
                 {{O}{1}}%
                 {{P}{1}}%
                 {{Q}{0}}%
                 {{R}{0}}%
                 {{S}{0}}%
                 {{T}{2}}%
                 {{U}{1}}%
                 {{V}{2}}%
                 {{W}{0}}%
                 {{X}{2}}%
                 {{Y}{1}}%
                 {{Z}{1}}%
                 {{Aa}{4}}%
                 {{Ab}{6}}%
                 {{Ac}{1}}%
                 {{Ad}{1}}%
                 {{Ae}{6}}%
                 {{Af}{2}}%
                 {{Ag}{0}}%
                 {{Ah}{3}}%
                 {{Ai}{2}}%
                 {{Aj}{1}}%
                 {{Ak}{0}}%
                 {{Al}{0}}%
                 {{Am}{0}}%
                 {{An}{0}}%
                 {{Ao}{0}}%
                 {{Ap}{4}}}

% Utility to add Data
% e.g \AddToData \SvendData{WW}{5}
% \newcommand*\AddToData [3]{\odef #1{#1{{#2}{#3}}}}
% But would be better utility to update the private \Svend@Values@..,
% \Svend@Counts@.., \Svend@Cuml@.. macros

\makeatletter

% Possible values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 hard coded here, we associate to each
% a macro to hold the number of its occurrences

\newcommand*\ResetCounts {%
    \xintFor ##1 in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}\do {\@namedef{Svend@Counts@##1}{0}}%
}

% \odef does \def with one expansion of replacement text

\newcommand*\ParseData [1]{%
% Defines the private macros underlying \elev and \HowMany
  \xintFor* ##1 in {#1}\do {%
    \expandafter\odef\csname Svend@Values@\@firstoftwo ##1\endcsname {\@secondoftwo ##1}%
    \edef\Svend@tmp {Svend@Counts@\@secondoftwo ##1}%
    \expandafter\odef\csname\Svend@tmp\endcsname 
                   {\the\numexpr\csname\Svend@tmp\endcsname + \@ne}%
  }%
}%

\newcommand*\ComputeCumu {%
% Computes and stores iteratively cumulative counts
% Again the possible values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 hard coded in this approach
  \xintFor ##1 in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}\do {%
    \xintifForFirst {\odef\Svend@tmp{\romannumeral-`0\HowMany{0}}}
                    {\odef\Svend@tmp{\the\numexpr\Svend@tmp+\HowMany{##1}}}%
    \expandafter\let\csname Svend@Cumul@##1\endcsname \Svend@tmp
    \xintifForLast {\let\HowManyTotale\Svend@tmp }{}%
  }%
}

% Percentiles: 
% I understand there are various definitions, I used this one : 
%
% P(x) (x=0,1,..,100) is the smallest value V such as the frequency of 
% event {v<= V} is at least x\%. Thus P(100) is the largest V and P(0) is the
% smallest V.

% cf http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile 

% first (expandable) method:
% \xintiLt {a}{b}{DO THIS IF a<b}{DO THIS IF a>=b}
% \newcommand*\Percentile [1]{%
%     \xintifLt {\HowManyCumu {0}/\HowManyTotale}{#1/100}{% percentile at least 1
%     \xintifLt {\HowManyCumu {1}/\HowManyTotale}{#1/100}{% percentile at least 2
%     \xintifLt {\HowManyCumu {2}/\HowManyTotale}{#1/100}{% percentile at least 3
%     \xintifLt {\HowManyCumu {3}/\HowManyTotale}{#1/100}{% percentile at least 4
%     \xintifLt {\HowManyCumu {4}/\HowManyTotale}{#1/100}{% percentile at least 5
%     \xintifLt {\HowManyCumu {5}/\HowManyTotale}{#1/100}{% percentile at least 6
%     \xintifLt {\HowManyCumu {6}/\HowManyTotale}{#1/100}{7%
%     }{6}%
%     }{5}%
%     }{4}%
%     }{3}%
%     }{2}%
%     }{1}%
%     }{0}%
% }    

% Possibly faster expandable method, does three comparisons: 
% (based on a binary tree of the possible values)
% The other method above does between 1 and 7 comparisons depending on the input
% Speed gain would show only for larger range of values, for example from 0 to
% 127 rather than from 0 to 7
\newcommand*\Percentile [1]{%
    \xintifLt {\HowManyCumu {3}/\HowManyTotale}{#1/100}
      {% percentile at least 4
      \xintifLt {\HowManyCumu {5}/\HowManyTotale}{#1/100}
        {\xintifLt {\HowManyCumu {6}/\HowManyTotale}{#1/100}{7}{6}}
        {\xintifLt {\HowManyCumu {4}/\HowManyTotale}{#1/100}{5}{4}}%
      }
      {% percentile at most 3
      \xintifLt {\HowManyCumu {1}/\HowManyTotale}{#1/100}
        {\xintifLt {\HowManyCumu {2}/\HowManyTotale}{#1/100}{3}{2}}
        {\xintifLt {\HowManyCumu {0}/\HowManyTotale}{#1/100}{1}{0}}%
        }%
}%



\newcommand*\elev        [1]{\csname Svend@Values@#1\endcsname }
\newcommand*\HowMany     [1]{\csname Svend@Counts@#1\endcsname }
\newcommand*\HowManyCumu [1]{\csname Svend@Cumul@#1\endcsname }

\makeatother

\ResetCounts
\ParseData\SvendData
\ComputeCumu

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{14}{c}}
\toprule
\elev{A}  & \elev{B}  & \elev{C}  & \elev{D}  & \elev{E}  & \elev{F}  & \elev{G}  &
\elev{H}  & \elev{I}  & \elev{J}  & \elev{K}  & \elev{L}  & \elev{M}  & \elev{N}    \\[0.5ex]
\elev{O}  & \elev{P}  & \elev{Q}  & \elev{R}  & \elev{S}  & \elev{T}  & \elev{U}  &
\elev{V}  & \elev{W}  & \elev{X}  & \elev{Y}  & \elev{Z}  & \elev{Aa} & \elev{Ab}   \\[0.5ex]
\elev{Ac} & \elev{Ad} & \elev{Ae} & \elev{Af} & \elev{Ag} & \elev{Ah} & \elev{Ai} &
\elev{Aj} & \elev{Ak} & \elev{Al} & \elev{Am} & \elev{An} & \elev{Ao} & \elev{Ap}   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
% THIS WOULD BE OK:

% \begin{tabular}{*{8}{c}}
% \toprule
% \xintFor #1 in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}\do {{$F(#1)$}&}{$F(7)$}\\
% \xintFor #1 in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}\do
%                {\xintRound{1}{\HowManyCumu{#1}/\HowManyTotale [2]}&}100\\
% \bottomrule
% \end{tabular}

% BUT THE SAME WITH 
% \begin{tabular}{*{7}{S[table-format = 2.1]}S[table-format = 3]}
% DOESN'T WORK: ON NE PEUT PAS UTILISER \xintFor DANS UN TABULAR AVEC siunitx !!

%  We can use expandable macros with siunitx

\def\RowA #1{{$F(#1)$}}% EXTRA BRACES NEEDED FOR SIUNITX !!
\def\RowB #1{\xintRound{1}{\HowManyCumu{#1}/\HowManyTotale [2]}}

\begin{tabular}{*{7}{S[table-format = 2.1]}S[table-format = 3]}
\toprule
% PURELY EXPANDABLE MACROS: those work with siunitx ...
% ... BUT don't try to define a macro with parameter here :((
\xintListWithSep {&}{\xintApply\RowA {{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}}}\\
\xintListWithSep {&}{\xintApply\RowB {{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}}}&100\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{*{9}{c}}
\toprule
% strange standalone problem with too long line from
% \xintFor #1 in {0, 10, 25, 33, 50, 66, 75, 90} \do {\textit{Pe}$(#1)$&}\textit{Pe}$(100)$\\
\xintFor #1 in {0, 10, 25, 33, 50, 66, 75, 90} \do {$q(#1)$&}$q(100)$\\
\xintFor #1 in {0, 10, 25, 33, 50, 66, 75, 90} \do {$\Percentile{#1}$&}$7$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also got into trouble with `standalone` (as indicated near the bottom of the code) and even `dvipng` joined the comedy of complaints, for reasons unbeknownst to me.

---

**Second Answer**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
%\usepackage[paperwidth=25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xintfrac, xinttools}
% EXTENDED DATA
\newcommand*\SvendData
                {{{A}{6}}%
                 {{B}{0}}%
                 {{C}{0}}%
                 {{D}{3}}%
                 {{E}{0}}%
                 {{F}{2}}%
                 {{G}{1}}%
                 {{H}{1}}%
                 {{I}{1}}%
                 {{J}{5}}%
                 {{K}{0}}%
                 {{L}{3}}%
                 {{M}{7}}%
                 {{N}{3}}%
                 {{O}{1}}%
                 {{P}{1}}%
                 {{Q}{0}}%
                 {{R}{0}}%
                 {{S}{0}}%
                 {{T}{2}}%
                 {{U}{1}}%
                 {{V}{2}}%
                 {{W}{0}}%
                 {{X}{2}}%
                 {{Y}{1}}%
                 {{Z}{1}}%
                 {{Aa}{4}}%
                 {{Ab}{6}}%
                 {{Ac}{1}}%
                 {{Ad}{1}}%
                 {{Ae}{6}}%
                 {{Af}{2}}%
                 {{Ag}{0}}%
                 {{Ah}{3}}%
                 {{Ai}{2}}%
                 {{Aj}{1}}%
                 {{Ak}{0}}%
                 {{Al}{0}}%
                 {{Am}{0}}%
                 {{An}{0}}%
                 {{Ao}{0}}%
                 {{Ap}{4}}%
                 {{NA}{6.5}}%
                 {{NB}{0.5}}%
                 {{NC}{0.5}}%
                 {{ND}{3.5}}%
                 {{NE}{0.5}}%
                 {{NF}{2.5}}%
                 {{NG}{1.5}}%
                 {{NH}{1.5}}%
                 {{NI}{1.5}}%
                 {{NJ}{5.5}}%
                 {{NK}{0.5}}%
                 {{NL}{3.5}}%
                 {{NM}{7.5}}%
                 {{NN}{3.5}}%
                 {{NO}{1.5}}%
                 {{NP}{1.5}}%
                 {{NQ}{0.5}}%
                 {{NR}{0.5}}%
                 {{NS}{0.5}}%
                 {{NT}{2.5}}%
                 {{NU}{1.5}}%
                 {{NV}{2.5}}%
                 {{NW}{0.5}}%
                 {{NX}{2.5}}%
                 {{NY}{1.5}}%
                 {{NZ}{1.5}}%
                 {{NAa}{4.5}}%
                 {{NAb}{6.5}}%
                 {{NAc}{1.5}}%
                 {{NAd}{1.5}}%
                 {{NAe}{6.5}}%
                 {{NAf}{2.5}}%
                 {{NAg}{0.5}}%
                 {{NAh}{3.5}}%
                 {{NAi}{2.5}}%
                 {{NAj}{1.5}}%
                 {{NAk}{0.5}}%
                 {{NAl}{0.5}}%
                 {{NAm}{0.5}}%
                 {{NAn}{0.5}}%
                 {{NAo}{0.5}}%
                 {{NAp}{4.5}}}

\makeatletter

% \odef does \def with one expansion of replacement text

\newcommand*\SvendValues {}
\newcommand*\SvendNumValues {}


\newcommand*\ParseData [1]{%
% Defines the private macros underlying \elev and \HowMany
% This version creates \SvendValues ordered list of values.
%
% For inner efficiency this \SvendValues is with braces, not commas
% (to be used with \xintFor* not \xintFor)
%
% The values do not have to be integers. But they must be numeric quantities
% as understood by xintfrac.
%
  \def\SvendValues {}%
  \def\SvendNumValues {0}%
  \xintFor* ##1 in {#1}\do 
  {%
% get the possibly new value
    \odef\Svend@tmpD {\@firstoftwo ##1}%
    \odef\Svend@tmpV {\@secondoftwo ##1}%
% and insert it at the correct location in \SvendValues
% (the better would be to manage some kind of heap tree but I have not
% invested the needed time)
%
    \def\SvendValues@Tmp {}%
    \def\Svend@tmpflag  {0}%
% 0 = initial state, 
% 1 = inserted, finish, 
% 2 = was already there
    \xintifForFirst 
    {\odef\SvendValues {\expandafter{\Svend@tmpV}}%
     \def\SvendNumValues{1}%
     \expandafter\odef\csname Svend@Counts@\Svend@tmpV\endcsname {0}}% will be increased below
    {\xintFor* ##2 in {\SvendValues}\do 
      {%
      \if0\Svend@tmpflag\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
         {\xintifCmp {\Svend@tmpV}{##2}
          {\def\Svend@tmpflag{1}%
           \oodef\SvendValues@Tmp
                 {\expandafter\SvendValues@Tmp \expandafter{\Svend@tmpV}{##2}}}% new < old
          {\def\Svend@tmpflag{2}\odef\SvendValues@Tmp {\SvendValues@Tmp {##2}}}% old = new
          {\odef\SvendValues@Tmp {\SvendValues@Tmp {##2}}}% new > old
         }
         {\odef\SvendValues@Tmp{\SvendValues@Tmp {##2}}}%
      }%
     \if0\Svend@tmpflag
         \oodef\SvendValues@Tmp{\expandafter\SvendValues@Tmp\expandafter {\Svend@tmpV}}%
     \fi
     \let\SvendValues\SvendValues@Tmp
%\typeout{\SvendValues}% debugging
     \if2\Svend@tmpflag
      \else
      % new value
      \expandafter\odef\csname Svend@Counts@\Svend@tmpV\endcsname {0}% will be increased below
      \odef\SvendNumValues {\the\numexpr\SvendNumValues+\@ne}\fi
    }%
% continued as in earlier code
    \expandafter\odef\csname Svend@Values@\Svend@tmpD\endcsname {\Svend@tmpV}%
    \expandafter\odef\csname Svend@Counts@\Svend@tmpV\endcsname 
                   {\the\numexpr\csname Svend@Counts@\Svend@tmpV\endcsname + \@ne}%
  }% end of external \xintFor loop
}%

\newcommand*\ComputeCumu {%
% Computes and stores iteratively cumulative counts
% THIS VERSION USES \SvendValues
  \xintFor* ##1 in {\SvendValues}\do {%
    \xintifForFirst {\odef\Svend@tmp{\romannumeral-`0\HowMany{##1}}}
                    {\odef\Svend@tmp{\the\numexpr\Svend@tmp+\HowMany{##1}}}%
    \expandafter\let\csname Svend@Cumul@##1\endcsname \Svend@tmp
    \xintifForLast {\let\HowManyTotale\Svend@tmp }{}%
  }%
}

% Percentiles: 
%
% P(x) (x=0,1,..,100) is the smallest value V such as the frequency of 
% event {v<= V} is at least x\%. Thus P(100) is the largest V and P(0) is the
% smallest V.

% 
% THIS VERSION USES \SvendValues
% It has nothing hardcoded.

\catcode`_ 11
\def\Percentile@helper #1#2% space below is to stop premature expansion
    { \if1\xintifLt {\HowManyCumu {#2}/\HowManyTotale}{#1/100}{0}{1}\xint_dothis{#2}\fi}

\newcommand*\Percentile [1]{% expandable !
    \xintApplyUnbraced{\Percentile@helper {#1}}\SvendValues\xint_orthat {}%
}

\catcode`_ 8

\newcommand*\elev        [1]{\csname Svend@Values@#1\endcsname }
\newcommand*\HowMany     [1]{\csname Svend@Counts@#1\endcsname }
\newcommand*\HowManyCumu [1]{\csname Svend@Cumul@#1\endcsname }

\let\firstoftwo\@firstoftwo
\let\secondoftwo\@secondoftwo
\makeatother


\ParseData\SvendData
\ComputeCumu
%\typeout{\meaning\SvendValues}

% for first tabular
% WITH BEAMER I CAN NOT DEFINE THIS IN THE FRAME !!!!!!

% ANY \newcommand MUST BE IN THE PREAMBLE WITH BEAMER !!!!!!

\newcommand*\Row [1]{\stepcounter{rowcount}%
                     \elev{\firstoftwo #1}%
                     \ifnum\value{rowcount}<14
                     \expandafter\firstoftwo\else\expandafter\secondoftwo\fi
                     {&}{\setcounter{rowcount}{0}\\[0.5ex]}}

% for middle data (not a tabular, would be too wide)
\newcommand*\ShowCumu [1]{$F(#1)=\xintRound{1}{\HowManyCumu{#1}/\HowManyTotale [2]}$}

% for third tabular

\newcommand*\RowA [1]{$q(#1)$}%
\newcommand*\RowB [1]{$\Percentile{#1}$}



\newcounter{rowcount}


\begin{document}\small

% DEBUGGING (not possible with  Beamer! because of #1...)
% \HowMany{0}

% \xintFor*#1 in \SvendValues\do {[#1,\HowMany{#1}], }
% \SvendNumValues

% \xintNthElt{0}{\SvendData}

% \HowManyTotale

\begin{frame}
\centering
\setcounter{rowcount}{0}%

\begin{tabular}{*{14}{c}}
\toprule
\xintApplyUnbraced \Row\SvendData
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

% (This is too wide hence would make letters in my png appear too small)

% DEFINITIONS LIKE THIS MUST BE MOVED TO PREAMBLE IF BEAMER CLASS !!
% \def\RowA #1{{$F(#1)$}}% EXTRA BRACES NEEDED FOR SIUNITX !!
% \def\RowB #1{\xintRound{1}{\HowManyCumu{#1}/\HowManyTotale [2]}}

% \centerline{\begin{tabular}{*{\SvendNumValues}{S[table-format = 2.1]}}
% \toprule
% \xintListWithSep {&}{\xintApply\RowA \SvendValues}\\
% \xintListWithSep {&}{\xintApply\RowB \SvendValues}\\
% \bottomrule
% \end{tabular}}

\xintListWithSep{,\quad }{\xintApply\ShowCumu \SvendValues}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{*{10}{c}}
\toprule
\xintListWithSep {&}{\xintApply\RowA {{0}{10}{25}{33}{50}{66}{75}{90}{100}}}\\
\xintListWithSep {&}{\xintApply\RowB {{0}{10}{25}{33}{50}{66}{75}{90}{100}}}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Is it possible to avoid hard-coding the values by doing something like `\def\maximum{7}` and then `\xintFor ##1 in {0, 1, ..., \maximum}\do`?

Comment: Btw. If I can't use the code with [`beamer`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer), it's not relevant in this particular case but thank you very much for the code!

Comment: You can use the code with beamer. It is only the last tabular which would not work as it uses `\xintFor`. The previous two work, and the code in the preamble too.

Comment: `\xintFor ##1 in {0, 1, ..., \maximum}` is not possible but something like `\xintFor* ##1 in {\xintSeq[1]{0}{\maximum}}` is. I will edit the answer to illustrate it.

Comment: Hmmm ... The point is that I need the quartiles calculated within `beamer` slides.

Comment: This is no problem if the use of the `\xintFor` is as here in the defined macros. The only problem is when I wanted to construct the tabulars themselves: in your original code they are written item by item. Anyway I need to finish first the more general code.

Comment: Okay. I'm looking forward to seeing your improved code!