# How to get (print) the number of elements in the row with the largest number of elements in the array?

Tags: expl3, latex3, count

For example, in the following MWE, there're 12 elements in the first line of the array while the second line of the array has 10 elements, so I'd like a command that can automatically printed the number of elements in the row with the largest number of elements in the array: 12.

MWE:

```tex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_node_row_seq  
\seq_new:N \l_node_tmp_seq 
\cs_set:Npn \timelist #1 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_node_row_seq {;} {#1}
  \int_step_inline:nn{\seq_count:N \l_node_row_seq}
  {
    \seq_if_exist:cF {l_node_row_##1_seq}
    {
      \seq_new:c {l_node_row_##1_seq}
    }
    \exp_args:Ncx\seq_set_from_clist:Nn {l_node_row_##1_seq} {\seq_item:Nn \l_node_row_seq{##1}}
  }
}

\cs_set:Npn \PrintTime [#1][#2] {
  \tl_if_empty:nTF { #1 }
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nTF { #2 }
    {
      \seq_use:Nn \l_node_row_seq {,}
    }
    {
      \int_step_inline:nn{\seq_count:N \l_node_row_seq}
      {
        \seq_put_right:Nn \l_node_tmp_seq {\seq_item:cn {l_node_row_##1_seq}{#2}}
      }
      \seq_use:Nn \l_node_tmp_seq {,}
    }
  }
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nTF {#2}
    {
      \seq_use:cn {l_node_row_#1_seq}{,}
    }
    {
      \seq_item:cn {l_node_row_#1_seq}{#2}
    }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}
\timelist{
3,.,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,5;
2,.,7,1,8,2,8,1,8,2}
\tikz
{
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,12}
    {
      \node[xshift=.5*\x in] at (-\x,1) {\texttt{\PrintTime[1][\x]}};
      \node[xshift=.5*\x in] at (-\x,0) {\texttt{\PrintTime[2][\x]}};
    }
}
\end{document}
```

[image: The number of elements in the row with the largest number of elements in the array is 12]

Now if there's a command, for example, the name of the command is `count`, then if I input

```tex
\count{
3,.,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,5;
2,.,7,1,8,2,8,1,8,2
}
```

Then it will print `12` automatically. How can I realize it?

Comment: Might you be interested in a LuaLaTeX-based solution? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico I'd like a solution based on XeLaTeX, because my projects are all written based on XeLaTeX

Comment: I just found a similar question, but it was for a one-dimensional array, not a two-dimensional array: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308239/count-number-of-elements-in-predefined-list